# 15bit struct in C

Tags: c, struct

I need to create a memory struct for a project in which each word comprises 15 bits. When I check the size of the array I get that it is 2000 bytes in size, I assume it is because compiler byte alignment.

Is there a way to create the struct that it will be 1875 bytes in size?

This is the code I used:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#pragma pack(push,1)
struct myword
{
    unsigned int val : 15;
};
struct mymemmory{

    struct myword arr[1000];
};
#pragma pack(pop)


int main()
{
    int size = sizeof(struct mymemmory);
    printf("Size of arr: %d\n",size);
    return 0;
}
```

When I use `#pragma pack(push,0)` I get that the size is 4000 bytes.

Comment: If you want to pack to something other than byte boundaries, I suspect you will have to write the code to do shifting and masking yourself.

Comment: a struct or any other objects in C can't start in the middle of a byte address because they must be addressable. If that 1 bit is really necessary, pack it another way, like a struct with 15 `uint16_t` elements

Comment: You will probably have to use a byte array of size 1875 and manually parse it into 15bit chunks with shifting

Comment: The type of bit-twiddling required is messy and error prone, going that route you might as well consider better performing compression schemes. In any event, if you are particularly starved for space then I'd consider doing the reverse here. That is to squeeze some other bit flag into the remaining bit of the 1000 slots if you have got one.

Comment: Thanks, I was just curious due to a projoct i got for my studies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you have a machine with 15-bit `char`s, you'll need to do a lot of bit manipulation to spread your 15-bit values over up to three `unsigned char`s using shifts and bit masks.

The following code works for machines with `CHAR_BIT` between 8 and 15 inclusive.

`set15_le(mem, index, val)` has `mem` pointing to an array of `unsigned char` providing the storage for an emulated array 15-bit words, `index` is the index of a 15-bit word, and `val` is a 15-bit value to be stored.  `get15_le(mem, index)` returns the 15-bit word from the specified index.  The 15-bit words are stored in "little-endian" byte order.

`set15_be(mem, index, val)` and `get15_be(mem, index)` are similar to the above, except that the 15-bit words are stored in "big-endian" byte order.

The `main` function tests both flavors, by storing a set of 15-bit, pseudo-random numbers in the array, reading them back, and checking they match the expected values.

```
#include <limits.h>

#if CHAR_BIT > 15
#error "Unsupported CHAR_BIT value"
#endif

unsigned short get15_le(const unsigned char *mem, unsigned long index)
{
    unsigned long mem_index;
    unsigned int mem_bitpos;
    unsigned int val_bitpos;
    unsigned short val_mask;
    unsigned short val;

    mem_index = (index * 15) / CHAR_BIT;
    mem_bitpos = (index * 15) % CHAR_BIT;
    val = 0;
    val_bitpos = 0;
    val_mask = (1U << 15) - 1;
    while (val_mask)
    {
        unsigned int nbits;
        unsigned char mem_mask;
        unsigned char mem_byte;

        nbits = CHAR_BIT - mem_bitpos;
        if (nbits > 15 - val_bitpos)
        {
            nbits = 15 - val_bitpos;
        }
        mem_mask = val_mask << mem_bitpos;
        mem_byte = mem[mem_index];
        mem_byte &= mem_mask;
        val |= (mem_byte >> mem_bitpos) << val_bitpos;
        mem_bitpos += nbits;
        if (mem_bitpos == CHAR_BIT)
        {
            mem_bitpos = 0;
            mem_index++;
        }
        val_bitpos += nbits;
        val_mask >>= nbits;
    }
    return val;
}

void set15_le(unsigned char *mem, unsigned long index, unsigned short val)
{
    unsigned long mem_index;
    unsigned int mem_bitpos;
    unsigned int val_bitpos;
    unsigned short val_mask;

    mem_index = (index * 15) / CHAR_BIT;
    mem_bitpos = (index * 15) % CHAR_BIT;
    val_bitpos = 0;
    val_mask = (1U << 15) - 1;
    val &= val_mask;
    while (val_mask)
    {
        unsigned int nbits;
        unsigned char mem_mask;
        unsigned char mem_byte;

        nbits = CHAR_BIT - mem_bitpos;
        if (nbits > 15 - val_bitpos)
        {
            nbits = 15 - val_bitpos;
        }
        mem_mask = val_mask << mem_bitpos;
        mem_byte = mem[mem_index];
        mem_byte &= ~mem_mask;
        mem_byte |= ((val >> val_bitpos) << mem_bitpos) & mem_mask;
        mem[mem_index] = mem_byte;
        mem_bitpos += nbits;
        if (mem_bitpos == CHAR_BIT)
        {
            mem_bitpos = 0;
            mem_index++;
        }
        val_bitpos += nbits;
        val_mask >>= nbits;
    }
}

unsigned short get15_be(const unsigned char *mem, unsigned long index)
{
    unsigned long mem_index;
    unsigned int mem_bitpos;
    unsigned int val_bitpos;
    unsigned short val_mask;
    unsigned short val;

    mem_index = (index * 15) / CHAR_BIT;
    mem_bitpos = CHAR_BIT - (index * 15) % CHAR_BIT;
    val = 0;
    val_bitpos = 15;
    val_mask = (1U << 15) - 1;
    while (val_mask)
    {
        unsigned int nbits;
        unsigned char mem_mask;
        unsigned char mem_byte;

        nbits = mem_bitpos;
        if (nbits > val_bitpos)
        {
            nbits = val_bitpos;
        }
        val_bitpos -= nbits;
        mem_bitpos -= nbits;
        mem_mask = (val_mask >> val_bitpos) << mem_bitpos;
        mem_byte = mem[mem_index];
        mem_byte &= mem_mask;
        val |= (mem_byte >> mem_bitpos) << val_bitpos;
        if (mem_bitpos == 0)
        {
            mem_bitpos = CHAR_BIT;
            mem_index++;
        }
        val_mask >>= nbits;
    }
    return val;
}

void set15_be(unsigned char *mem, unsigned long index, unsigned short val)
{
    unsigned long mem_index;
    unsigned int mem_bitpos;
    unsigned int val_bitpos;
    unsigned short val_mask;

    mem_index = (index * 15) / CHAR_BIT;
    mem_bitpos = CHAR_BIT - (index * 15) % CHAR_BIT;
    val_bitpos = 15;
    val_mask = (1U << 15) - 1;
    val &= val_mask;
    while (val_mask)
    {
        unsigned int nbits;
        unsigned char mem_mask;
        unsigned char mem_byte;

        nbits = mem_bitpos;
        if (nbits > val_bitpos)
        {
            nbits = val_bitpos;
        }
        val_bitpos -= nbits;
        mem_bitpos -= nbits;
        mem_mask = (val_mask >> val_bitpos) << mem_bitpos;
        mem_byte = mem[mem_index];
        mem_byte &= ~mem_mask;
        mem_byte |= ((val >> val_bitpos) << mem_bitpos) & mem_mask;
        mem[mem_index] = mem_byte;
        if (mem_bitpos == 0)
        {
            mem_bitpos = CHAR_BIT;
            mem_index++;
        }
        val_mask >>= nbits;
    }
}

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct mymemory
{
    unsigned char content[(1000 * 15 + CHAR_BIT - 1) / CHAR_BIT];
};

int main(void)
{
    struct mymemory mem;
    unsigned long i;
    unsigned short v;

    printf("Memory size for 1000 15-bit words = %lu bytes (%lu bits)\n",
            (unsigned long)sizeof(mem.content),
            (unsigned long)sizeof(mem.content) * CHAR_BIT);
    printf("Testing little-endian version\n");
    memset(mem.content, 42, sizeof(mem.content));
    srand(5);
    for (i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        v = rand() & ((1U << 15) - 1);
        set15_le(mem.content, i, v);
    }
    srand(5);
    for (i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        unsigned int w;

        v = rand() & ((1U << 15) - 1);
        if ((w = get15_le(mem.content, i)) != v)
        {
            printf("Error at word %lu! got %u, expected %u\n", i, w, v);
            break;
        }
    }
    if (i == 1000)
    {
        printf("Passed!\n");
    }
    printf("Testing big-endian version\n");
    memset(mem.content, 42, sizeof(mem.content));
    srand(23);
    for (i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        v = rand() & ((1U << 15) - 1);
        set15_be(mem.content, i, v);
    }
    srand(23);
    for (i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        unsigned int w;

        v = rand() & ((1U << 15) - 1);
        if ((w = get15_be(mem.content, i)) != v)
        {
            printf("Error at word %lu! got %u, expected %u\n", i, w, v);
            break;
        }
    }
    if (i == 1000)
    {
        printf("Passed!\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I corrected the packing of bits into chars for `set15_be` and `get15_be` so that when 15-bit values are written as left-to-right binary with consecutive values appearing in left-to-right order, the bit stream can be broken into a sequence of chars in left-to-right order.

Answer (score 2):

No, there isn't. If you need bit level granularity, you have to implement it yourself, making an array of the 1875 bytes and manually calculating indices and bit masks to extract the desired 15 bits. If you want to stay sane, you factor out this functionality into accessor functions, ideally using C++ or the like where you can make custom classes that abstract away the work entirely (so simple indexing use does all the "real index" and bit shift/mask work behind the scenes; `std::vector<bool>` already does something quite like this for single bits).

Of course, true sanity is realizing it's silly to quibble over 125 bytes. There are very few scenarios where saving one bit in sixteen for each value (especially for so few values) is worth it, and the ones I can think of (actually needing a compact representation on disk) are still handled better by converting from compact disk representation to expanded memory representation on read, and converted back on write, to avoid the hassle and computational overhead of dealing with all the shifting and masking on every read/write.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer